# Audio on Google Slides Using Google App Script

Tags: audio, google-apps-script, google-slides-api

How would you add audio to Google Slides using Google App Script?

I have tried following:

- embedding the video inside of a 0x0 pixels area, but Google Slides has removed HTML and iframe embedding.
- put the video behind everything, but that didn't work as I have a plain background and the video would start at the beginning of every new slide.
- using the Google App Script (using [this](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-oembed-examples/blob/master/oembed/js-example.html)), but I needed some HTML in my slide, which I couldn't have.

Is there any way to add audio to Google Slides?